# Exported database of PHPMyAdmin is smaller than the size of the database in PHPMyAdmin control panel

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I need to backup a website for one of our customers, and have exported both the files on the webserver and PHP database.

This PHP database is managed via PHPMyAdmin, and I have absolutely no knowledge about PHP or SQL...

I've noticed that the export of the database is around 4MB on my workstation, but the size of the database on PHPMyAdmin is 8.7 MB large. Is it possible that the export is a compressed file? 
How can I check if the export is done correctly? Is there a client app which I can use to view the SQL database?

Kind Regards

Comment: Seems like,`max no. of queries` interrupts exporting entire db

Answer (score 1):

If you selected a compression format from the phpMyAdmin export page, then it will be compressed using whichever you picked (zip and gzip are the two options available).

However, MySQL tables generally have overhead and extra space, so it's entirely possible (even quite likely) that what you're seeing is that "overhead" and not an accurate reflection of the actual size of the database in MySQL. This number can include any index or temporary data as well as extra disk space that isn't reclaimed after records are deleted.

One way to compare the original and backup could be with column counts, such as `` SELECT COUNT(`actor_id`) FROM `actor`; ``

Comment: This count query may be tedious, but by far the best way i found to compare DB.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but might help someone in need.
The quickest one of the best ways for me is to Export your database in chunks.

Steps:

1. Go to `phpMyAdmin`: On the left side, click on the name of your     database to populate it.
2. Check a few tables by clicking on the check-boxes to select them.
3. Scroll down to the last table and you'll see a drop-down list that
   has a default value that reads "With selected". Click it and select
   "Export", and your first chunk of database will be exported.
4. Repeat the above steps until all tables have been exported and
   you're good to go.